# Remove given parts of a string with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
$ echo '<a href="mailto:NA?Subject=AB42525216 - FOOBAR bla bla - bla">NA</a>'
<a href="mailto:NA?Subject=AB42525216 - FOOBAR bla bla - bla">NA</a>
$ echo '<a href="mailto:NA?Subject=AB42525216 - FOOBAR bla bla - bla">NA</a>' | sed 's/SOMEMAGIC/NA/g'
NA
```

**My question**: how can I remove the string in the "echo" with SOMEMAGIC? The delimiter could be > I think

Comment: What part of string do you want to remove?

Comment: Usually it's better to use a parser to process HTML.

Comment: `sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/'` would work on that particular input. But so would `cut -d \> -f2- | cut -f\< -f1`

Comment: @evachristine: Do you mean replace the whole line by `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to extract the value that are inside `<a href>xx</a>` tag. If yes then your command should be like this,

GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^<a [^>]*>([^<]*)<.*$/\1/g' file
```

Traditional sed:

```
sed 's/^<a [^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '<a href="mailto:NA?Subject=AB42525216 - FOOBAR bla bla - bla">NA</a>' | sed -r 's/^<a [^>]*>([^<]*)<.*$/\1/g'
NA

$ echo '<a href="mailto:NA?Subject=AB42525216 - FOOBAR bla bla - bla">NA</a>' | sed 's/^<a [^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/g'
NA

$ echo '<a href="mailto:NA?Subject=AB42525216 - FOOBAR bla bla - bla">fooooooooooooooobaaaaaaaaaar</a>' | sed 's/^<a [^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/g'
fooooooooooooooobaaaaaaaaaar
```